# Facebook load times are very slow, but other pages are fast, and >12Mbit/s up & down

Tags: performance, browser, connection, facebook

I have measured 12 Mbit/s up and downstream. I have a wireless Network Adapter called Asus PCE-N53 (300Mbps 11n Dual band Wireless LAN PCI-E Card) and is connected to my local wireless router. I have Windows 7.

Facebook is very sluggish and load times for facebook are very bad, especially for images and video clips. Sometimes it just stops. Most other pages load very fast. What could be the cause of this? IPv6 timeouts or anything like that? I have tried flushing DNS cache, but the problem persists. Does anyone have a clue to what causes this issue? Cellphones on wifi do not seems to have this problem. Galaxy S4 and Iphone 4+.

ping and tracert for facebook.com gives:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ping www.facebook.com

Skickar ping-signal till star.c10r.facebook.com [31.13.91.2] med 32 byte data:
Svar från 31.13.91.2: byte=32 tid=289ms TTL=83
Svar från 31.13.91.2: byte=32 tid=256ms TTL=83
Svar från 31.13.91.2: byte=32 tid=530ms TTL=83
Svar från 31.13.91.2: byte=32 tid=999ms TTL=83

Ping-statistik för 31.13.91.2:
    Paket: Skickade = 4, Mottagna = 4, Förlorade = 0 (0 %),
Ungefärlig överföringstid i millisekunder:
    Lägsta = 256 ms, Högsta = 999 ms, Medel = 518 ms

C:\Windows\System32>tracert www.facebook.com

Spårar väg till star.c10r.facebook.com [31.13.64.1] över högst 30 hopp:

  1     6 ms    32 ms    44 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    38 ms    11 ms    12 ms  gw-n1-vrr-a31.ias.bredband.telia.com [90.225.79.1]
  3    12 ms    17 ms    10 ms  kbn-b4-link.telia.net [62.115.139.162]
  4    19 ms    97 ms    82 ms  kbn-bb3-link.telia.net [62.115.142.212]
  5   298 ms   109 ms    74 ms  hbg-bb1-link.telia.net [213.155.135.126]
  6    33 ms   135 ms   117 ms  adm-bb3-link.telia.net [213.155.136.158]
  7    41 ms    31 ms    28 ms  adm-b5-link.telia.net [62.115.140.153]
  8    40 ms    42 ms    33 ms  facebook-ic-156922-adm-b5.c.telia.net [62.115.11.50]
  9     *        *        *     Begäran gjorde timeout.
 10     *        *        *     Begäran gjorde timeout.
 11   132 ms    98 ms    43 ms  edge-star-shv-01-ams2.facebook.com [31.13.64.1]


Spårning utförd.



C:\Windows\System32>tracert -6 www.facebook.com
Det går inte att matcha måldatorns namn www.facebook.com. (doesn't work!)

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Testing this page:
[Max connections test](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/max-connections.php?t=1434406712)

Results in 
**Page load time:    24266 ms** in Chrome and a few broken pictures,
while
**Page load time:    8740 ms** in firefox with a lot of broken pictures.

I guess because they time out differently, or?

I have a quad-core intel i5 2500k with 16GB of RAM and a 250MB SSD.

Comment: What browser do you use? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Can you post the traceroute to www.facebook.com and not facebook.com? Are you certain you are using IPv6 to connect to FB or IPv4? It would help to understand what your issues may be.

Comment: Answering Paul's question is the important bit now: making sure we understand the situation and circumstances. And Paul knows what he's talking about ;-)

Comment: You are using the wrong hostname in your traceroute. Performance of `facebook.com`  is irrelevant, because all you need to get from there is a redirection to `www.facebook.com`.

Comment: OK so I just a get DNS redirect to the www domain of facebook.com, right? I am not certain of much actually.

Comment: You have roundtrip times ranging from 43 milliseconds to 1 second. That's a pretty extreme amount of jitter. Your ping and traceroute commands got different IP addresses. But as far as I can tell, they are located close enough that you should be seeing similar roundtrip times. And since each of them displays significant jitter on their own, I conclude that the difference between ping and traceroute measurements is simply because the roundtrip time changed in the meantime.

Comment: You need to find out at which hop the jitter is introduced. A single traceroute command is not enough to identify that, so you either have to run traceroute many times or use a tool which can trace the connection periodically until it produce a clear picture. One such tool is mtr.

Comment: Can you post your computer specs please?